# Jenkins read a file and report it's null or not

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I am trying to generate a report with in jenkins pipeline and putting a condition where I want to check whether the generated file is empty or not.

If it's empty go to another condition and if it's not empty execute the other steps.

```
def status = sh(returnStatus: true, script: "git status > output.txt")
File conflict = new File("output.txt")
println "The file ${conflict.absolutePath} has ${conflict.length()} bytes"

if ( "${conflict.length()}" == "0" ) {
    println "\u001B[32m[INFO] conflicts are there"
    def output = readFile('conflict_output.txt').trim()
    println output                                                      
}
```

This is not working. Git status output has some data, and it should not be 0 bytes. Everytime I ran it's entering in to this if condition.

Answer (score 5):

You can use this code instead of your code:

```
def output_list = readFile("output.txt")
if (output_list.size() == 0) {
    // your code
}
```

and you can **.split** your file based on your delimiter.